# Join elements of list with various conditions

Tags: python, list, enumerate

For this list

```
pays_list=["France","francais","€200", "1kg","20€","Espagne","espagnol","€20",
"Allemagne","allemand","deutsch","€100","2kg", "300€",
"Belgique","belge","frite","€30"]

pays_concatenate=[]

for i, elm in enumerate(pays_list):
    if "€" in elm:
        del pays_list[i]
    pays_list=pays_list

for i in pays_list:
    for e in i:
        if any(e in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" for e in i):
            print(i)
```

"i" will be equal to elements with a capital letter...(France, Espagne etc ...)

I want to add the elements before the next capital letter

I except this output

```
pays_concatenate=["France francais","Espagne espagnol",
    "Allemagne allemand deutsch",
    "Belgique belge frite"]
```

Comment: Your code doesn't give at all the output you show. Why France as 5 values, then Espagne has 3, then 6, then 4. if there is no rule that will be hard

Comment: Assuming your actual indentation is correct, did you mean: `pays_concatenate.append(elm)`?

Comment: what's your expetec output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `itertools.groupby` to group the strings into those with and without a `"€"`, and join each group with `" "`:

```
import itertools

pays_list=["France","francais","€200", "1kg","20€","Espagne","espagnol","€20",
"Allemagne","allemand","deutsch","€100","2kg", "300€",
"Belgique","belge","frite","€30"]


pays_concatenate = [
    " ".join(g) 
    for _, g in itertools.groupby(pays_list, lambda e: "€" in e)
]
print(pays_concatenate)
# ['France francais', '€200', '1kg', '20€', 'Espagne espagnol', '€20',
#  'Allemagne allemand deutsch', '€100', '2kg', '300€',
#  'Belgique belge frite', '€30']
```

Comment: I completed my code with your answer @Samwise

Answer (score 0):

Thank Samwise, i complete your code to have my output

```
pays_concatenate = [
" ".join(g) 
for _, g in itertools.groupby(pays_list, lambda e: "€" in e)
]


for i,elm in enumerate(pays_concatenate):
    if not any(s in elm for s in ('€', 'kg')):    
        pays_concatenate=elm
        print(pays_concatenate)
```

and my output :

```
France francais
Espagne espagnol
Allemagne allemand deutsch
Belgique belge frite
```

Comment: This is just a copy of my answer, with some extra stuff added to match the stuff that you just added to your own question.  Why not just accept my answer since it solved your original problem?

Comment: If you want but your answers was incomplete

Comment: The answer was only "incomplete" because you added on to the question two months after you posted it.  The edit history is right there for everyone to see.  :P

Comment: my wish was not to add anything but to reformulate my request...